# How to import a component and use it in accordion in react native

Tags: react-native, accordion

I have a functional component, I wanted  to import that component and use it inside `Accordion` which is a third party package for making collapsible. Package name: `react-native-collapsible/Accordion`

My Component:

```
function _renderADHeader() {

...
...
...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(_renderADHeader);
```

In my main file I have exported this component in the following way:

`import {_renderADHeader} from './sections/address/headerBar/index';`

And I wanted to use it inside `Accordion`

```
<Accordion
  renderHeader={_renderADHeader}
/>;
```

But, I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: renderHeader is not a function.`

I tried to write `this._renderHeader` , but that is also not working. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: import RenderADHeader from './sections/address/headerBar/index'

Comment: <Accordion
  renderHeader={RenderADHeader}
/>;

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: what error is coming ?

Comment: It's the same as before

Comment: can we have quick call. ?